# the_excerpt is displaying excerpts of every post

Tags: posts, excerpt

I have a simple page for outputting all posts (index. php) 
Unfortunately the excerpt shows me the excerpts of all entries. 
what's the mistake?

```
                    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="col col-md-6">
                        <div class="thumbnail equalize-content">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                            <div class="caption">
                                <span class="date"><time datetime="<?php the_time('Y-m-d'); ?>"
                                                         pubdate><?php the_date(); ?></time></span>
                                <a href="<?php esc_url(the_permalink()); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"
                                   rel="bookmark">
                                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
                                <p>

                                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <a class="btn" href="<?php esc_url(the_permalink()); ?>">Artikel lesen</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Can you add a link to your site, or post a snippet of the output? Also, it often helps to boil down the code to the minimum required to reproduce it, so remove all the unnecessary HTML and other PHP.

Comment: Well, you're looping through all posts (the `while (have_posts()) : the_post();` part)  and then display the title and excerpt for every post. That's exactly what this should do. What do you want to achieve instead?

Comment: @swissspidy Yes, the problem is that every loop shows all excrept information (from every post).

Comment: So what do you want? No excerpts at all? Only show the excerpt of the first post? You need to be more clear. If you want to remove the excerpts, just remove the `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>` line.

Comment: @swissspidy here the link to the blog: http://blog.stiftungschweiz.ch/

Comment: @MikeDanthine Looks like you were able to resolve the issue. What was the cause? Also, if my tips have helped it would be great if you could mark the answer as accepted :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your site, the problem seems to be a little different.

For every post, the excerpt of the *first* post is shown. And not just once, but three times. This happens only on the website, but not the RSS feed or the REST API.

Since the code you provided looks fine, it seems that something on your site is messing with the excerpt in some other way. This can be a plugin or something in your theme mixing up the global `$post` object or hooking into the `the_excerpt` or `get_the_excerpt` filters.

To debug this, you should first disable all your plugins to see if the bug persists.

After that, you can hook into `get_the_excerpt` to see whether the post object has been modified by using good ol' `var_dump()` (or just use Xdebug):

```
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', function( $excerpt, $post ) {
  var_dump( $excerpt, $post );
  return $excerpt;
}, 10, 2 );
```

If the output doesn't look right, see which other functions hook into this filter by using something like this:

```
global $wp_filter;
print_r( $wp_filter['get_the_excerpt'] );
```

If everything looks alright, check the `the_excerpt` filter as well:

```
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', function( $excerpt ) {
  var_dump( $excerpt, get_post() );
  return $excerpt;
} );

global $wp_filter;
print_r( $wp_filter['the_excerpt'] );
```